# Android Chrome failed to repeat very long background image

Tags: css, google-chrome, android-chrome

One of my project requires to display a very long image (height to width ratio is very high, which is 1920x7500) as background image. The background image should repeat at y-axis, too.

However, I have noticed that only Android Chrome have issue in rendering this long image as background image with `repeat-y`. When I set `background-repeat: no-repeat;` the background image is shown.

This does not happen in Android Firefox and Desktop Chrome.

I am able to fulfill the requirement with other methods, but would like to know if this is a bug in Android Chrome.

Minimum reproduction link (background image does not work):

https://jsfiddle.net/9vpdrazs/4/show

Using `background-repeat: no-repeat;` rule (background image is working):

https://jsfiddle.net/9vpdrazs/7/show

Minimum reproduction but with < 1000px height image (background image is working):

https://jsfiddle.net/9vpdrazs/8/show